# Kazam: Invalid section name

Tags: 20.04, python3, kazam

I installed kazam on Ubuntu 20.04.1 using the below commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sylvain-pineau/kazam
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

While starting kazam, I am getting the below error:

```
/usr/bin/kazam:32: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a
version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to
ensure that the right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import
Gtk WARNING Kazam - Failed to correctly detect operating system.
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/webcam.py:24:
PyGIWarning: GUdev was imported without specifying a version first.
Use gi.require_version('GUdev', '1.0') before import to ensure that
the right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import GObject,
GUdev Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/kazam", line
147, in <module>
    from kazam.app import KazamApp   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/app.py", line 36, in <module>
    from kazam.backend.prefs import *   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/prefs.py", line 566, in
<module>
    prefs = Prefs()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/prefs.py", line 142, in
__init__
    self.config = KazamConfig()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/config.py", line 87, in
__init__
    ConfigParser.__init__(self, self.DEFAULTS[0]['keys'])   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 639, in __init__
    self._read_defaults(defaults)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 1219, in _read_defaults
    self.read_dict({self.default_section: defaults})   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 754, in read_dict
    self.set(section, key, value)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/backend/config.py", line 150, in
set
    self.add_section(section)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 1208, in add_section
    super().add_section(section)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 656, in add_section
    raise ValueError('Invalid section name: %r' % section)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 20210115:** the newest kazam 1.5.4-0ubuntu6 from this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esylvain-pineau/+archive/ubuntu/kazam) works normally.
Thanks to the PPA owner!

---

Notes:

1. some systems need manual installation of `gir1.2-gudev-1.0` package.
2. possible alternative is [OBS Studio snap](https://snapcraft.io/obs-studio).

Comment: But kazam 1.4.5 does not support the webcam. I wanted to record the webcam for one of my presentations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for contacting the PPA owner. :)

Comment: I think you have to try [OBS Studio snap](https://snapcraft.io/obs-studio).

Comment: Thank you. OBS studio works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply use:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall kazam
```

And remove `~/.config/kazam/kazam.conf`